# OAuth multipart post in Erlang

Tags: twitter, oauth, erlang

I am trying to extend this library https://github.com/tim/erlang-oauth-examples to allow the client to make multipart posts (as necessary for Twitter's statuses/update_with_media). So far the, this is my attempt at the extra final signing and authentication logic that is necessary. The formation of the Body, using Boundaries is done elsewhere, and I don't think is the stumbling block.

```
oauth_post({multipart, Boundary}, URL, Body, Consumer, Token, TokenSecret) ->
    BodyH   = base64:encode_to_string(crypto:hash(sha, Body)),                                
    Signed  = oauth:sign("POST", URL, [{"oauth_body_hash", BodyH}], Consumer, Token, TokenSecret),
    {[[{ "oauth_signature", Sig}],
      [{"oauth_body_hash", BBody}]], Rest} = 
        proplists:split(Signed, ["oauth_signature", "oauth_body_hash"]),                
    Encoded = [ {"oauth_signature", oauth:uri_encode(Sig)} 
              , {"oauth_body_hash", oauth:uri_encode(BBody)}
              | Rest],
    Sorted  = lists:sort(Encoded),
    Auth    = lists:flatten(string:join([ K++"=\""++V++"\"" || {K,V} <- Sorted], ", ")),      
    OAuth   = "OAuth " ++ Auth,
    ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" ++ Boundary,                                
    Headers = [ {"Authorization", OAuth}
              , {"Content-Type", ContentType}
              , {"Content-Length", integer_to_list(length(Body))}],                           
    Request = {URL, Headers, ContentType, Body},                                              
    httpc:request(post, Request, [], []).
```

But so far this method call fails to Authenticate. Can anyone, with this domain expertise, see what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

### After Answer

Per Paul's answer below, this is what I ended up using. Updated my fork of the library too.

```
oauth_post({multipart, Boundary}, URL, Body, Consumer, Token, TokenSecret) ->
    BodyH   = base64:encode_to_string(crypto:hash(sha, Body)),
    Signed  = oauth:sign("POST", URL, [{"oauth_body_hash", BodyH}]
                  , Consumer, Token, TokenSecret),
    {AuthorizationParams, []} = 
        lists:partition(fun({K, _}) -> lists:prefix("oauth_", K) end, Signed),
    Headers = [ oauth:header(AuthorizationParams)],
    ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" ++ Boundary,
    Request = {URL, Headers, ContentType, Body},
    httpc:request(post, Request, [], []).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your code **only URI-encodes the signature and the body hash**. All `oauth_*` parameters must be URI-encoded, and especially `oauth_nonce` which is a Base64 string in this [OAuth library](https://github.com/tim/erlang-oauth/blob/118e9f7284c81cb72e131e20bcecf5872a5cbe97/src/oauth.erl#L80).

```erlang
Nonce = base64:encode_to_string(crypto:rand_bytes(32)), % cf. ruby-oauth
```

As a side note:

- Fetching the value for key `"oauth_body_hash"` does not make sense since you passed this value in the first place (it is in `BodyH`).
- You don't need to sort the oauth_ parameters in the signature.
- You don't need the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers, inets' httpc will add them for you unless you pass `headers_as_is` option.

Simply do:

```erlang
oauth_post({multipart, Boundary}, URL, Body, Consumer, Token, TokenSecret) ->
    BodyH   = base64:encode_to_string(crypto:hash(sha, Body)),                                
    Signed  = oauth:sign("POST", URL, [{"oauth_body_hash", BodyH}], Consumer, Token, TokenSecret),
    % URI encode values returned by oauth:sign/6 for the Authorization header
    Auth    = lists:flatten(string:join([ K++"=\""++oauth:uri_encode(V)++"\"" || {K,V} <- Signed], ", ")),
    OAuth   = "OAuth " ++ Auth,
    ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" ++ Boundary,                                
    Headers = [ {"Authorization", OAuth} ],
    Request = {URL, Headers, ContentType, Body},                                              
    httpc:request(post, Request, [], []).
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul! Total braino about forgetting to encode all of the parameters. The library even has a nice method call just for that:        `oauth:header(AuthorizationParams)`.